# Is a good idea to use nested class when I want to separate some query strings by category?

Tags: c#

To be more clear, I give an example

I have a class which is responsible with sql queries. Of course, I have more domains/fields and more queries.

I want to separate them by fields to be easily used by other programmers.

So the class

```
public static class QueryClass
{
   public static class Field1 
   {
      public static string AQuery { get { return "a"; } }
      public static string BQuery { get { return "b"; } }
   }

   public static class Field2
   {
      public static string AQuery { get { return "a1"; } }
      public static string BQuery { get{ return "b1"; } }
   }
}
```

Example, how to use:

```
string aSimpleQueryField1 = QueryClass.Field1.AQuery;
string aSimpleQueryField2 = QueryClass.Field2.AQuery;
```

It's a good idea to use nested class ? Or is another best way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't see any problem with this, actually think this is a good idea, especially from coding point of view. If you have different queries for different data, it would be intuitive enough to have:

`QueryBase..QueryUserInfo.Something()` or `QueryBase.QueryStats.Something()`

Answer (score 0):

It seems fine to me, but if I get it correctly, I would make the strings [readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) fields.

Comment: If is getter, I guess that is enough. Cannot use readonly if static keyword was provided.

Comment: I see, I would use `readonly` to make it more obvious. Besides, when you're only providing the constant getter, using `readonly` has a slightly lower overhead.

Comment: You can use `static readonly` but in this case `const` would be better. (you cannot use `static const` because `const` is `static` by default). And fields would be better then properties in this case.

Comment: @Rafal You're right, after giving it more thought, I also prefer `const`.

Answer (score 0):

its fine I think but I should add Constructor

Comment: Did you notice that everything is `static` ?

Comment: @MichaelSwan but everything is now hardcoded how are you ever gonna fill it with data?